# Powershell - browse for folder - a better way to do this?

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am working with a script that prompts the user to select a folder or folders.  The code follows.

```
$wrkfolder = "C:\MyPC\WorkingFolder"              #workfolder starting location

$app = New-Object -ComObject shell.Application

# Display Browse for File to select a folder or ALL folders
$folder = $app.BrowseForFolder(0,"Select Folder -- Cancel to select ALL",0,$wrkfolder)

    if ($folder.self.path -ne "") {
        $fldr = $folder.Self.Path
        $fldrName = $folder.Self.Name
        }
```

Currently, that prompts the user with a folder browse input dialog, and if the user selects CANCEL, it will select **all** the folders in the $wrkfolder.  Or, if they select a single folder, it will return that folder.  If the user closes the dialog, it returns $null (which is the same thing as selecting Cancel).

I'd like for it the script to allow the user to have the option to select a folder, select multiple folders, select ALL folders, and for the Cancel to actually close the dialog & return a value that I could then exit the script.

Without re-inventing the wheel on this form, is there an easy way to prompt the user with a browse input folder dialog & allow them to select 1+ folders, all folders or to cancel the script? There has to be a better way to do this than what I've got thus far.

Answer (score 1):

This won't help you unless you're running the PowerShell V3 beta but for future reference, you can use the `Out-GridView's` new `PassThru` parameter e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | Out-GridView -PassThru | ...
```

`Out-GridView` allows multi-selection and you can also cancel the whole pipeline operation via the cancel button.